# Two elements are algebraic over $ F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over $F$, then show that $[F(a, b) :F] =[F(a, b), F(a)] [F(a), F]$. Please help to solve this problem using an example also.

Comment: .... You are aware that $[C:A]=[C:B][B:A]$ is a standard theorem for a sequence of field extensions $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$F(a,b)$ is both  an $F$- vector space  and an $F(a)$-vector space. So it's exactly the same situation as this well-known situation:

> Let $E$ be a $\mathbf C$-vector space. Then, as an $\mathbf R$-vector space, we have
>   $$\dim_{\mathbf R}E=\dim_{\mathbf C} E\cdot  \dim_{\mathbf R}\mathbf C.$$

Answer (score 0):

$F(a,b)=(F(a))(b)$, i.e. the field generated over $F$ by $a$ and $b$ is the field generated by $b$ over the field $F(a)$ generated by $a$.

We have $F \subseteq F(a) \subseteq F(a,b)$, then we see that $[F(a,b):F]=[F(a,b):F(a)][F(a):F]$.

> **EX**: $ [\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3 ):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3 ):\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 )][\mathbb Q(\sqrt2):\mathbb Q]=2\times2=4 $.
>
> **EX**: $ [\mathbb Q(^6\sqrt2 ):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(^6\sqrt2 ):\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 )][\mathbb Q(\sqrt2):\mathbb Q]=3\times2=6 $.